# Flutter: Clicking on TextFormField redirects me back to Home:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

I only have TextFormFields in 2 places in my app. Once in my Login Widget and second in my PinWidget, which is meant to set a personal pin.

Home: is always the login widget. There the first function redirectIfLoggedIn is executed which redirects to another widget if a flag is set in the sharedPreferences that you are already logged in.

In the Login Widget everything works fine but in the PinWidget I am redirected to Home as soon as I click on the TextFormField.

[gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghcgV.gif)

Login Widget:

```
import 'package:global_jets/custom_code/actions/api.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/custom_code/actions/notification_api.dart';
import '../components/customer_logo_header_widget.dart';
import '../components/powered_by_widget.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/custom_code/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:global_jets/custom_code/actions/functions.dart';

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoginWidgetState createState() => _LoginWidgetState();
}

class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  TextEditingController textController1;
  TextEditingController textController2;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final api = new ApiController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController1 = TextEditingController();
    textController2 = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    redirectIfLoggedIn(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -1),
                child: CustomerLogoHeaderWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.35),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 250,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0x00EEEEEE),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/login-background.jpg',
                      ).image,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.5),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0x00EEEEEE),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: textController1,
                        obscureText: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Benutzername',
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                              fontFamily: 'Square',
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              useGoogleFonts: false,
                            ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.2),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: textController2,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Passwort',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x98000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x98000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style:
                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Square',
                                    // color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    useGoogleFonts: false,
                                  ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.01, 0.68),
                        child: FFButtonWidget(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            // NotificationsApi.showNotification(
                            //   title: 'Tizian Thost',
                            //   body: 'lorem ipsum',
                            //   payload: 'tizian.thost',
                            // );
                            bool success = false;
                            success = await api.login(textController1.text, textController2.text);
                            if (success) {
                              await Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      NavBarPage(initialPage: 0),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          text: 'Login',
                          options: FFButtonOptions(
                            width: 130,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Color(0xFFFFD457),
                            textStyle:
                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2.override(
                                      fontFamily: 'Square',
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      useGoogleFonts: false,
                                    ),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                child: PoweredByWidget(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void redirectIfLoggedIn(context) async {
  globals.isLoggedIn = await isLoggedIn();
  if (globals.isLoggedIn) {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => NavBarPage(initialPage: 0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/login/login_widget.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/settings/pin/pin.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'flutter_flow/internationalization.dart';
import 'clock/clock_widget.dart';
import 'user/user_widget.dart';
import 'login/login_widget.dart';
import 'applications/applications_widget.dart';
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // globals.isLoggedIn = await isLoggedIn();  
  // await setPin();
  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
    null,
    [
      NotificationChannel(
          channelGroupKey: 'basic_channel_group',
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          channelName: 'Basic notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
          defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
          ledColor: Colors.white)
    ],
    // Channel groups are only visual and are not required
    channelGroups: [
      NotificationChannelGroup(
          channelGroupkey: 'basic_channel_group',
          channelGroupName: 'Basic group'
      )
    ],
    debug: true
  );
  AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
    if (!isAllowed) {
      // This is just a basic example. For real apps, you must show some
      // friendly dialog box before call the request method.
      // This is very important to not harm the user experience
      AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
    }
  });
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
  
  MyApp({this.isLoggedIn, this.homePage});
  final isLoggedIn;
  final homePage;

  static _MyAppState of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale _locale;
  ThemeMode _themeMode = FlutterFlowTheme.themeMode;
  void setLocale(Locale value) => setState(() => _locale = value);
  void setThemeMode(ThemeMode mode) => setState(() {
        _themeMode = mode;
        FlutterFlowTheme.saveThemeMode(mode);
  });  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Global Jets',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        FFLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: _locale,
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', '')],
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      home: LoginWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class NavBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  NavBarPage({Key key, this.initialPage}) : super(key: key);

  final int initialPage;

  @override
  _NavBarPageState createState() => _NavBarPageState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with NavBarPage.
class _NavBarPageState extends State<NavBarPage> {
  
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentPage = widget.initialPage ?? _currentPage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> _children = [
      ClockWidget(),
      UserWidget(),
      ApplicationsWidget(),
      PinWidget(),
    ];
    // final currentIndex = tabs.keys.toList().indexOf(_currentPage);
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentPage,
        children: _children,
      ),      
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentPage,
        onTap: (i) => setState(() => _currentPage = i),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF313131),
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFFFD457),
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0x8AFFFFFF),
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
              size: 24,
            ),
            label: 'Arbeitszeit',
            tooltip: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.userTie,
              size: 24,
            ),
            label: 'Mein Konto',
            tooltip: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidFileAlt,
              size: 24,
            ),
            label: 'Anträge',
            tooltip: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidFileAlt,
              size: 24,
            ),
            label: 'Einstellungen',
            tooltip: '',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Pin Widget:

```
import 'package:global_jets/components/customer_logo_header_widget.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/components/powered_by_widget.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_icon_button.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:global_jets/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PinWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PinWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PinWidgetState createState() => _PinWidgetState();
}

class _PinWidgetState extends State<PinWidget> {
  TextEditingController textController;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  static GlobalKey<FormState> _pinFormKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController = TextEditingController();
    _pinFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF313131),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: FlutterFlowIconButton(
          borderColor: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: 30,
          borderWidth: 1,
          buttonSize: 60,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Arbeitszeit Verlauf',
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).title2.override(
                fontFamily: 'Square',
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22,
                useGoogleFonts: false,
              ),
        ),
        actions: [],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.15),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Form(
                      key: _pinFormKey,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: textController,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    width: 1,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    width: 1,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .bodyText1
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.9),
                            child: FFButtonWidget(
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('Button pressed ...');
                              },
                              text: 'Ändern',
                              options: FFButtonOptions(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 40,
                                color: Color(0xFFFFD457),
                                textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                    .subtitle2
                                    .override(
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.6),
                      child: Text(
                        'Pin festlegen',
                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                              fontFamily: 'Square',
                              useGoogleFonts: false,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
              child: PoweredByWidget(),
            ),
            CustomerLogoHeaderWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have already searched Google and Stackoverflow, also found similar problems but no solution.

I have experimented with different variations of FormKeys with final and static but nothing seems to work.

In other places I have DateTimePicker, but the problem does not occur with them.

I should add that the base of the app was created with Flutterflow but has been heavily modified.

Comment: It is not possible to make a comment. You do not need lots of Stack Widgets for such a simple page. What I can suggest is to use Flutter Inspector (Dart DevTools) to see where(which widget) you are clicking exactly and try to debug.

Answer (score 0):

in your first picture it looks like everything is wrapped in a gesture detector that may be an issue

Answer (score 0):

bro you gotta stop using flutter flow or you have to find alternatives every time when you want to use  flutter f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).